# How can I get a count of a Word called 'MSH' used multiple times in a file with a single UNIX command - AIX 6.1?

Tags: text-processing, command, aix

How can I get a count of a Word called MSH used multiple times in a file with a single UNIX command - AIX 6.1 ?

Comment: Why a single command?

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
awk '{a+=gsub(/MSH/,"")}END{print a}' infile
```